# Understanding big O notation

Tags: asymptotics, definition

I'm not a mathematician by any stretch and I'm trying to translate some maths terms into simple maths terms. Please don't laugh, I do consider this complicated!

The equations in question are

```
O(n) and O(n ^ 2)
```

Now, I have read up on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) about this but it has been written (IMO) for people who already understand it!

I believe n ^ 2 translates to `the power of`, in this case it is also the equivalent of squaring it (i.e. `n * n`).

However, I can't get my head around `O` in terms of what it is describing. Wiki says it's the limiting behaviour. So, does this mean `O` is more of a description than a function or command? In my understanding, the following 2 equations are the same

```
O(n^2)

n^2
```

Comment: many years ago I asked this in a math forum, they said $f(x)=O(g(x))$ iff $(\exists M>0)(\forall x>M)(|f(x)|\le M|g(x)|)$. by the way a notation like $f(x)<< g(x)$ has more to say.

Comment: I will never, ever, understand even a quarter of that :)

Comment: $(\exists M>0)(\forall x>M)(|f(x)|\le M|g(x)|)$ means: "There's some $M>0$ such that for all $x>M$ we have $f(x)<Mg(x)$" (replace $x$ by $n$ )

Comment: @CutieKrait Hm in such precise language, it seems strange not to consider O(g(x)) to be a class of functions, as in the second answer to this question. I feel the = should be replaced by "is element of"

Comment: Of course: $O(\cdot)$ is a set of functions. But almost nobody avoids the abuse of notation $f=O(g)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quickly, $O(n^2)$ is *any* function $f=f(n)$ such that $$\left| \frac{f(n)}{n^2} \right|$$ remains bounded as $n \to +\infty$. It may be $n^2$ itself, but it may also be $n$, or $\sin \cos n$, etc.

Comment: This is much easier for me to understand, thank you for taking the time. Is O also "order of" ?

Comment: Well, the big-O is a notation that is sometimes understood with some differences by scientists. I would rather use a different notation for $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2}=L\neq 0.$$ However, some scientists identify the two cases.

Answer (score 5):

The formally correct $O$-notation has been explained in http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=296&t=31517&start=20 . Namely, suppose we have been given a positive $g$ defined in a punctured neighborhood of $x_0$. Now $O_{x_0}(g)$ is the class of all functions $f$ such that the ratio $f/g$ is bounded in some punctured neighbourhood of $x_0$. This definition and notation is more rigorous than for example the one given in some university's computer science courses.