# How to approximate a function in the limit $|x| << 1.$ Leading term and order of error?

Tags: limits, approximation

So basically I'm doing my first year of a natural sciences undergraduate course, and I came up against this series of questions.

"Approximate the following functions in the limit $|x| << 1.$ In each case give the leading term and order of the error."

So, how would I go about doing that, for instance with the function: $$f(X)=\frac{X^3+X}{X+8} ?$$ I could tell you that as $x\to 0$ this function $f(X) \to  0,$ but that's about it.

I think my biggest problem is that I'm not actually sure what it means by 'leading term' and 'order of error'.

I've met big O notation briefly, it was explained as "$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = O(g(x))$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ look the same around a."

I assume it relates to that, but I can find nothing among my lecture notes nor on Google as to what this question actually wants from me, so if somebody could explain, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: "In each case" ???

Comment: Lookup "big-O" notation.

Comment: Have you tried Taylor expanding the function: $f(X) = (X^3+X)(X+8)^{-1}$, in the limit for small $X$? The leading term would be the first non-zero term in the expansion, then the order of error would be the next highest power of $X$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry I don't get what you mean by that. There's no $\vert{x}\vert$ in OP's function?

Comment: @TroyG: sorry, my bad.

Comment: @TroyG That's been a big help, thanks. Could you please explain what O() actually is? All I can find on it seems to be in the context of computer programming.

Comment: @Vpen One writes $f=o(g)(x\to{a})$ if the function $f(x)$ decreases faster or grows slower than the function $g(x)$ as $x\to{a}$, loosely speaking. So for example, $\sin{x}=x+o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391212/understanding-big-o-notation) may be relevant for you.